# Analytics session add to cart always at zero

Tags: php, google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

In my ecommerce (custon solution in php) I have inserted the script for the google analytics add to cart event when the add to cart button is pressed.

```
gtag('event', 'add_to_cart', {
        "items": [{
            "id"        : "P001",
            "name"      : "Description",
            "brand"     : "Brand",
            "category"  : "",
            "variant"   : "1",
            "quantity"  : 1,
            "price"     : 10
        }]
    });
```

I find the event on analytic in section Real Time --> Events, but if I move to Conversions--> E-commerce --> Purchase Behaviour the value of Sessions with addition to cart is always ZERO.
All other sessions are valued

Answer (score 0):

In official documentation price have the quotes, try to set it like it:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce